Horror movie - Kids on bus attacked by "scarecrow" monster near barn
It's color movie .. aired before 2012 (at least).
It included bunch of kids/teens on bus who went on the trip.
he ghost/villain hunted victims after every interval of 23 years or so .. it wasn't killed in the end .. 
The person who helped few kids escape was on wheelchair at the end of movie .. he's telling about the incident that happened (before 23 years or so .. ) to a bunch of kids .. and said (while showing 'em the body of ghost kinda like scarecrow) "that it's about time for him to wake up" .. 
The movie mostly took place near barn/isolated place.         

It's Jeepers Creepers 2 (2003)
Wikipedia:

Plot: Three days after the events of the first film, the Creeper,
  disguised as a scarecrow, abducts young Billy Taggart in front of
  Taggart Sr. and Billy's older brother, Jack Jr.
The following day, a school bus carrying a high school basketball team
  and cheerleaders suffers a blowout, after one of the wheels is hit by
  a hand-crafted shuriken made out of bone.
Cheerleader Minxie has a vision of Billy and Darry Jenner, the
  Creeper's victim from the first film, who both attempt to warn her
  about the Creeper, which then blows out another tire, disabling the
  bus. With the party stranded, the Creeper abducts the coaches and the
  bus driver, and singles out several of the occupants: Dante, Jake,
  Scotty, Bucky, and especially Double D. Minxie has another vision in
  which Darry explains that every twenty-third spring, for twenty-three
  days, the creature emerges from hibernation and hunts victims for
  specific body parts which it then consumes in order to replace those
  of its own, which she relays to the others.
After hearing numerous police reports, the Taggarts go hunting for the
  Creeper and make radio contact with the school bus. The Creeper
  attacks Bucky and is injured, and then kills Dante, using his severed
  head as a replacement for its own. The students leave the bus, where
  they are again attacked and chased into a field, where the Creeper
  kills Jake and takes Scotty. After the Creeper attacks Bucky at the
  bus again, Taggart shoots it with a home-made harpoon; however the
  Creeper escapes and flips the truck. Izzy, Rhonda, and Double D
  attempt to escape in a truck and are chased by the Creeper, causing
  the vehicle to crash. Despite missing an arm and leg, the Creeper
  continues to stalk Double D until Taggart intervenes by shooting it
  with a harpoon again. Taggart repeatedly stabs the Creeper in the
  chest and face but the creature goes into a hibernation state before
  it can die.
Twenty-three years later, a group of teenagers drive to Taggart's
  farm, where the Creeper is a sideshow attraction. They notice Taggart
  watching it with a harpoon gun at his side. When they ask him if he is
  waiting for something, Taggart looks up at the Creeper and says,
  "About three more days, give or take a day or two."
  Trailer

